# Slider max value calls multiple methods Swift

Tags: swift

I created a UI slider and it works but the problem I have now is that when it slides to the end before it returns, I made it call a function and now this function is called multiple times. I want this function to be called once. Below is my code

```
var startingFrame: CGRect?
    @objc func acknowledgeSwiped(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if let sliderView = sender.view {
            let translation = sender.translation(in: swipeView)
            switch sender.state {
            case .began:
                startingFrame = swipeImage.frame
                fallthrough
            case .changed:
                if let startFrame = startingFrame {

                    var movex = translation.x
                    if movex < -startFrame.origin.x { movex = -startFrame.origin.x }

                    let xMax = swipeView.frame.width - startFrame.origin.x - startFrame.width
                    if movex > xMax {
                        movex = xMax
                        acknowledge()
                    }

                    var movey = translation.y
                    if movey < -startFrame.origin.y { movey = -startFrame.origin.y }

                    let yMax = swipeView.frame.height - startFrame.origin.y - startFrame.height
                    if movey > yMax {
                        movey = yMax

                    }

                    sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: movex, y: movey)
                }
            default: // .ended and others:
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                    sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in such way:
1. Add members

```
var sliderSessionActive: Bool = False
var sliderFunctionCalled: Bool = False
```

2. Extract an event `.ended` into a distinct case.
3. Manage `sliderSessionActive`: set it to 'True' in `.began` and to `False` in `.ended`.
4. Set `sliderFunctionCalled` to `True` when you call your function, and to `False` in `.ended`.
5. Call your function only if the following condition is true: `sliderSessionActive and not sliderFunctionCalled`.

Comment: I do not understand your solution please